# str_replace() function not remove comma in PHP

Tags: php, replace

I have following code in PHP Code:

```
$net_pay = 8345.24;

$net_pay = str_replace(',', '', $net_pay);
$net_pay = number_format($net_pay);
```

str_replace does not remove the comma. If I var_dump, I got string(5) "8,345"

Any ideas? I just simply need to remove the commas so I can compute.

Comment: `str_replace` is replacing comma but when you used `number_format` it will again add a comma. What is the purpose to use `number_format`?

Comment: Why are you doing `number_format` again after `str_replace`

Comment: what is value for $emp->net_pay ?

Comment: I need to make 8345.24 to round off as 8345 so i use number_format.

Comment: Thanks now its working

Answer (score 2):

number_format() is just doing what it should.

> If all four parameters are given, number will be formatted with decimals decimals, dec_point instead of a dot (".") before the decimals and thousands_sep instead of a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Just call str_replace() after number_format().

Or more simply,

```
$net_pay = 8345.24;
$net_pay = number_format ($net_pay, 0 , "", "");
```

Comment: why call number format at all?

Comment: It formats the number to not contain decimals at all.

Comment: true. what about `$net_pay = (int) str_replace(',', '', $net_pay);`

Comment: Or $net_pay = number_format ($net_pay, 0 , "", ""); because then he wouldn't need str_replace() at all.

Answer (score 1):

remove the [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) it converts the numbers to comma separated value,try with this

```
 $net_pay = trim($emp->net_pay, ' ');
 $net_pay = mb_substr($net_pay, 0, 11);
 $net_pay = str_replace('.', '', $net_pay);
 echo $net_pay;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function formats a number with grouped thousands.
If you want to value without separation then don't use this.

Now for [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) value from decimal use below :

```
$randVal = round( 8345.24);
print($randVal);//Out put 8345
```

Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 0):

You have use number_format that may be causing issue. Please try below code.

```
$net_pay = "8,345";
$net_pay = str_replace(',', '', $net_pay);
echo $net_pay;
```

Answer (score 0):

`number_format` will add comma, so use that before `str_replace`. Use as below :

```
 $net_pay = 8345.24;
 $net_pay = number_format($net_pay);
 $net_pay = str_replace(',', '', $net_pay);
```

Comment: @Pamblam : the question has been changed. So it is required to use

Answer (score 0):

just make the net_pay variable string type make

```
$net_pay="2,334"; 
$net_pay = str_replace(',', '', $net_pay);
```